# Trim addtional whitespace between the names in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

How to trim the additional spaces present between the names in PySpark dataframe?

Below is my dataframe

```
    +----------------------+----------+
    |name                  |account_id|
    +----------------------+----------+
    | abc    xyz    pqr    |     1    |
    | pqm      rst         |     2    |
    +----------------------+----------+
```

Output I want

```
    +-------------+----------+
    |name         |account_id|
    +-------------+----------+
    | abc xyz pqr |     1    |
    | pqm rst     |     2    |
    +-------------+----------+
```

I tried using regex_replace, but it trims the space completely. Is there any other way to implement this ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to replace 1 or more spaces with 1 space, `regexp_replace(<your column>,\s+',' ')` should get you there.  `s+` means one or more spaces.

Comment: Yeah Got the output.Thanks for your support !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using 'regexp_replace(,'\s+',' ')' and I got the output.

```
df=df.withColumn("name",regexp_replace(col("name"),'\s+',' '))
```

Output

```
+-----------+----------+
| name      |account_id|
+-----------+----------+
|abc xyz pqr|     1    |
|    pqm rst|     2    |
+-----------+----------+
```